# How to edit the value updated in a database from the form using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I want to edit the data which is already in the databse.
Suppose I have updated my database, but after an year the user who has updated that database want to edit something like his address which is changed now through the form, then how can we do that. I am posting

```
      <?php
   // Create Local variable
        $taken = "false";
        $database = "railway";
        $password = "";
        $username = "root";

        // Main if statement
        //if($userreg && $passreg){

        // Connect to database
        $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', $username, $password,$database);

                        if ($con->connect_error) {
                            die("Connection failed: " . $con->connect_error);
                        }





                   ---------
              WHAT TO WRITE IN BETWEEN              
                 ----------------




      mysqli_close($con);
```

Suppose my table name is Railway and the attributes are **time**, **name**, **station_to**  and **station_from**.  I want to change the **name**.

Please write both the form as well as **php** and **mysql query**.

Comment: Not gonna write the code for you, but look at PDO. You're much better off using that instead of mysqli

Comment: use mysqli_query to query your table, then fill the form with the result using mysqli_fetch_assoc

Comment: You would write an `UPDATE` query.

Comment: It's very easy. See this example http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_update.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be something like this:

```
$sql = "UPDATE Railway SET name='Joe' WHERE id=5";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}
```

Comment: No one here got my question but crazy enough (for irrelevant comments) to comment. I am designing a form from where you can edit the database, and the person who is editing have no clue of database thing. He is just going to form and updating the edited thing say name in my example. SO I am asking how to write a query to take input from the user and that will be used to update the database.